# How to properly log Vulkan result type strings

Tags: vulkan

## Logging `VkResult` enum values

The `VkResult` enum contains a lot of values. Unfortunately though, they are C enums which aliases an integer, so I cannot easily just log their names to the console. For this purpose, I am envisioning a function which does something like this:

```cpp
void graphics::log_vk_result(VkResult result)
{
    switch (result)
    {
    case VK_SUCCESS:
        log_core_debug("VK_SUCCESS"); return;

    case VK_NOT_READY:
        log_core_debug("VK_NOT_READY"); return;
    [...]
}
```

But some of the enum values are only supported by certain extensions, as indicated [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkResult.html). An example: The extension `VK_EXT_debug_report` introduces the following value to the enumeration: `VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT`. So my idea for (potentially) more portable code would be something like this:

```cpp
void graphics::log_vk_result(VkResult result)
{
    switch (result)
    {
    [...]
#if defined(VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME)
    case VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT:
        log_core_debug("VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT");
#endif
}
```

I found this name by looking at the [extension manual page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_EXT_debug_report.html). I cannot easily see whether or not `VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME` is a macro or an enum - it is a `const char*` but stated under the section "New Enum Constants". So checking for this particular value, for this particular extension, was my default choice.

*[I do realize this extension is marked as deprecated, and I'm not using it! I only use it as an example here.]*

I have two questions:

1. Is this needed?
2. Is this the correct way of doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have unilateral knowledge of which version of the vulkan library headers your program will be compiled, or can you enforce that a certain minimum version of the vulkan library be compiled against? If so wrapping in preprocessor macros would be unnecessary as once a value has been added it remains in the headers, even if deprecated.

Comment: @vandench that's a good point - perhaps I should.

Comment: Always add a safe default case in either case, so you can handle future extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of this is unnecessary, since Vulkan SDK already includes the desired functionality:

```
#include <vulkan/vk_enum_string_helper.h>

void graphics::log_vk_result( const VkResult result ){
    log_core_debug( string_VkResult(result) );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P Protip: code does exactly the thing it is written in it.

Comment: @krOoze: That's obviously true. But future readers unfamiliar with the syntax may not be following your logic here. Help junior developers learn by offering an explanation that aids them in their education. That will make your answer more useful over time.

Comment: @krOoze That's an excellent suggestion! It also seems that this file provides "stringify" for a lot of other Vulkan enums and flag bits, which I'm sure can be very helpful in other situations. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly it's a header file so can't really use it in an interop manner when using a language other than C/C++.